# How to fix about empty option in select in Ionic with sqlite?

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have problem when making an ionic app about option in select just show blank screen like my screenshot below:
[image: blank screen for select option]

Its my controller js:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$http', '$timeout', '$interval', '$state', '$filter', '$location', 'DOLLTYPE', 'REGION', function($scope, $q, $http, $timeout,  $interval, $state, $filter, $location, DOLLTYPE, REGION) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('js/data2.json').success(function(result) {
              var region = result;
              console.log (region);
              deferred.resolve(region);
              for (var i = region.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
              REGION.add(region[i]); console.log('success')};
            return deferred.promise;
            })     

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(result) {
               var dolltype = result;
               console.log (dolltype);
               deferred.resolve(dolltype);
               for (var i = dolltype.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
               DOLLTYPE.add(dolltype[i]); console.log('success')};
            return deferred.promise;
            })  

 $scope.title = "Dashboard";


 $scope.dash = [];
 $scope.datas = [];
 $scope.avg = [];
 $scope.avgy = [];
 $scope.data = [[]];
 $scope.labels = [[]];
 $scope.date = [];


 $scope.place = [];
 $scope.ayv = [];

 $scope.dolltype = [];
 DOLLTYPE.all().then(function(dolltype){ 
 $scope.dolltype=dolltype
 })
 $scope.regiontype = [];
 REGION.all().then(function(regiontype){ 
 $scope.regiontype=regiontype
 })


 $scope.change = function(dash1) {
  $scope.place = dash1;
 }

 $scope.change2 = function(dash2) {
   $scope.doll= dash2.id;
 }


 $scope.place.name = 'Please select';

 $scope.$watchCollection('[place, doll]', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  $scope.colours = [
      { // Blue
        fillColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(47,64,200,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(67,43,177,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
      },
      { // Red
        fillColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(200,15,9,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(190,50,11,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
      },
       { // Green
        fillColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(18,177, 26,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(80,200,11,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
      }
    ];


 $http.get('js/data4.json').success(function(result) { 
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $scope.dash.msg  = result.message;
   $scope.prices = result.data;
   deferred.resolve($scope.prices);
   angular.forEach($scope.prices,function(value,index){
   var values =  {
                  value : value.value,
                  date : new Date(value.created_at.replace(/-/g,"/"))
    };

    $scope.datas.push(values.value);
    $scope.dash.price = $scope.datas[2];
    $scope.date.push($filter('date')(values.date,'dd-MMM'));    
    $scope.date.splice(2); 
    return deferred.promise;       
    })}).error(function(data, status) {


   console.error('Error', status, data);
   }); //End get price value

 $http.get('js/data5.json').success(function(result) { 
   $scope.averageprice = result.data;
   angular.forEach($scope.averageprice,function(value,index){
   var avgvalue =  {
                    average: value.average,
                    date : new Date(value.created_at.replace(/-/g,"/"))
    };
    console.log (avgvalue);
    $scope.avg.push(avgvalue.average);
    })}).error(function(data, status) {


   console.error('Error', status, data);
   }); //End get average price value

   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.get('js/data3.json').success(function(result) { 
   $scope.averageyearprice = result.data;
   deferred.resolve($scope.averageyearprice);
   console.log ($scope.averageyearprice);
   $scope.avgy.push($scope.averageyearprice.yearly_average);
   return deferred.promise;
   }).error(function(data, status) {


  }); //End get average year price value

  $scope.data[0] = $scope.datas;
  $scope.data[1] = $scope.avg;
  $scope.data[2] =  $scope.avgy;

  $scope.labels = $scope.date;
  console.log ($scope.data[0]);

  $scope.series = [$scope.place.name, 'All (Average)', 'All (YTD Year)']; 
  console.log ($scope.series); // Add information for the hover/touch effect

 })

}])
```

For HTML Template:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="{{title}}">
    <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-assertive"></ion-nav-bar> 
 <ion-content class="has-header"> 
      <div class="list">
          <div class="row item">
            <div class="col text-left assertive">   <select name='options' ng-model="dash2" ng-change="change2(dash2)" ng-options="DOLLtype as DOLLtype.name  for DOLLtype in dolltype">
             </select></div>
           <div class="col text-right assertive"> <select name='options' ng-model="dash1" ng-change="change(dash1)" ng-options="REGIONtype as REGIONtype.name for REGIONtype in regiontype">
             </select></div>
           </div>
           <div class="row item">
             <div class="col">Current Price</div>
             <div class="col text-right assertive">{{dash.price}} %</div>
             </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row item" id="container">
              <div class="col text-center">
                        <p>{{dash.msg}}</p>
                 <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data" labels="labels" series='series' height="100" legend="true" colours="colours"></canvas>
               </div>
              </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

How I can fix it? Its [my full example code](https://github.com/rebelholic/ionic-chart-selection) on github like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point your select model to whichever object in your `ng-options` list you want to be shown as the initial choice. So if you wanted the first option in your `$scope.dolltype` model to be displayed when your page loads you would put:

```
$scope.dash2 = $scope.dolltype[0];
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9gOhNU6zB9azmP1j1HJ?p=preview)

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){

  $scope.dolltype = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Item 1",
      basic_price: "7900000",
      created_at: "2015-06-14 17:00:00",
      updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Item 2",
      basic_price: "11000000",
      created_at: "2015-06-30 17:00:00",
      updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Item 3",
      basic_price: "9500000",
      created_at: "2015-06-30 17:00:00",
      updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    }
  ];

  $scope.dash2 = $scope.dolltype[0];

});
```

**EDIT**

Try putting your model definition inside your `then()` function:

```
DOLLTYPE
     .all()
     .then(function(dolltype){ 
         $scope.dolltype    = dolltype;
         $scope.dash2       = $scope.dolltype[0];
     });

 REGION
     .all()
     .then(function(regiontype){ 
        $scope.regiontype = regiontype;
        $scope.dash1      = $scope.regiontype[0];
     });
```

Also, I don't think you really need to use the `$q` service in your controller. The `$http` service already returns a promise so you don't need to create a new one with `$q.defer()`. I think you could change it to something like this:

```
$http
    .get('js/data2.json')
    .then(function(region) {

        var i = region.length -1;

        for (i; i >= 0; i--) {
            REGION.add(region[i]);
        };

    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log('Error fetching region data: ', error)
    };
```

Comment: Its still no luck because my app using sqlite plugin as offline storage after get data from server with simultaneously.

Comment: Its works like charm but the charts do not get any response based on selected option when loading first time

Comment: Ok, well if you feel my answer helped you with the initial problem regarding the empty options could you please mark it as the accepted answer and then start a new question with any other issues you have. Otherwise this question will get too long and bloated with code and chat that's irrelevant to the initial question. Thanks.